# How to save document directly from "network" tab in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

When we open a developer tool in Firefox, the "network" tab shows us resources that are loaded during the page load. If the resource is an image then there's a "Save Image As" menu item:

[image: screenshot]

Unfortunately, there's no such option if it's not an image and so far I have to copy url, paste it into another tab (I don't want the current page to be replaced!) then save.

I need a simple way to download a non-image resource directly from that table without reloading the page, switching to another tab, etc. Is there such a way?